# Does the average human eat their own body weight in food every month?

Tags: nutrition

I read this comic: [xkcd: The Race (Part 3)](http://xkcd.com/579/), and felt the urge to shout "Cite your references!".
[image: No, the best things about The Sarah Connor Chronicles were: (1) watching Sarah and Cameron try to pass for normal, and (2) Cameron throwing people and things through walls. Everything else was pretty secondary.]
Is it true? Does the average human consume their body weight in food in just over a month?

Comment: Well, I feel the urge to shout "Find a real notable claim!". xkcd in all honors, but it shouldn't count as notable.

Comment: Well... it *does* have some Nerd cred and you can expect people to cite stuff they read on xkcd, under the assumption that a sciency guy such as Randall would know what he's talking about.

Comment: Mr. Munroe's work does tend to be well-researched and thorough: http://xkcd.com/1040/

Comment: I think, however, this is not something where you'd have to dig for sources. Just analyze your own eating habit and do a rough order-of-magnitude calculation. Asking Wolfram Alpha what 300 slices of toast and 300 slices of cheese weigh together, that'd give 15 kg, which is off by a factor between 4 and 5 for me.

Comment: easy to investigate: get a kitchen scale and get a before and after for ever bit plate of food you eat (add snacks) until you get to your own bodymass, now you have 1 data point convince 10,000 random people to do the same and you have a half-decent study

Comment: @StuartPegg: I wouldn't have chosen that particular comic as an example. It doesn't cite its references.

Comment: Hint for future answerers: [EFSA](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/datexfoodcdb/datexfooddb.htm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [a study by the clinical nutrition centre of Addenbrokes Hospital, Cambridge, UK](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=846300) measuring the food consumed by a random sample of the population of a Cambridge village:

> The average weight of food eaten per day (excluding drinks) was 1277 g

That would give **a month's weight of food as around 38kg**. That's less than the average weight of a person, by a factor of around 2. I would expect an average British person to be eating significantly more than the average for people worldwide. They could be eating less than the average for the US, but I doubt it is by a factor of 2.

So **no the claim is not strictly true. But an error by a factor of two is actually pretty good for a web comic, and might be just a case of artistic license**

Comment: To be fair, the exact quote is "That's only slightly faster than the human average." Seeing as "slightly" is undefined it does become a matter of scale.

Comment: Having visited America, I would say that portions being a factor of two larger is an underestimate; but a single holiday's eating is hardly representative. I was also going to mention that including drinks may top that up, but a quick estimate indicates that it would be considerably more. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @StuartPegg I am sure the Brits are just as guilty of gluttony during holiday gatherings.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Sorry, to Americanise: "single holiday's eating" -> "single vacation's eating". It was a summer visit. :) But yes, Christmas is generally considered a time for stuffing yourself here too.

Comment: @StuartPegg I have been tracking my food pretty heavily lately (marathon training), and as an American I only eat ~1.1kg of food per day (~33kg/month). While the American average might be A LOT higher, I'm doubting double is likely.  And certainly world wide this seems unrealistic.  I think this is just one case where (unlike so many computer references, the XKCD creator did not do his homework).

Comment: @theJollySin: So we've got 2 data points on American consumption from extremely different situations between us. :) It's a good point about the world-wide averages. Food weight/nutrition ratios, consumption rates, and average bodyweight are likely to be somewhat different outside the western world, I imagine.

Comment: It also depends on the water content and energy density of the food you eat. For instance, I eat two salads per day with a total mass of about 1 kg. Add in snacks and an extra meal or two and I'm sure I eat at least 1.5 to 1.75 kg per day.

Comment: Americans eat a lot more, but Americans also weight a lot more. And the myth is about amount of food in relation to own weight.

Comment: To be fair, there is a joke in the claim. The Summer Glau figure says, "I eat my body weight in food every 31 days." She is a smaller than average person (52kg), so all she would have to do is eat 1677g a day.

Comment: I think it's highly sensitive to what you eat.  While I've never weighed my wife's food I would not be one bit surprised at her eating her body weight in a month.  She's very fond of fruit and in general likes juicy food.  In watermelon season I'm sure it doesn't even take her a month.

Comment: My 2 cents. She might be including liquids' weight in the daily eating, I guess that counting liquids the amount can easily increase by another 1500g

Comment: Or maybe she is referring to the dry weight of food and body....

Comment: @DJClayworth Please, where have you found the 1277g in the paper you reference?

Comment: Page 25 of the PDF, section RESULTS, subsection Weight of Food Eaten